# How do I save changes to a file edited in Terminal on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal, mamp-pro

I'm following this tutorial to get my postfix working with mamp pro. 
http://macnevada.net/mamp-pro-3-06-postfix-smart-host-not-working-on-osx-yosemite/

I've been following along well, but I'm at the part where I need to save the changes I made to the main.cf file in the terminal. I'm pretty new to the terminal. So how do I save the file?

Comment: It entirely depends on what editor you used to edit the file.  Can you provide us with more details?

Comment: In the terminal window it says nano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `nano`, there should be a menu at the bottom of the screen that looks something like:

```
^G Get Help  ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut Text  ^J Justify   ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Uncut Text^T To Spell  ^_ Go To Line
```

In this menu, the `^` represents the control (ctrl) key, so to exit, type CTRL-X.  This will prompt you to save the document.